# Is it OK to use while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) construct?

Tags: java, stream

I want to refactor the following code because I don't feel comfortable about using assignment inside comparison operator. It looks like pretty idiomatic C, but do you think this is a good practice in Java?

```
private void demoA(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        doSomething(line);          
    }
}
```

Here is an alternative.

```
private void demoB(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        doSomething(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I've stumbled across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677411/iterating-over-the-content-of-a-text-file-line-by-line-is-there-a-best-practic) asked couple years ago. It seems that opinions on whether it's OK or not are divided. However, both [Guava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655456/2517807) and [Commons IO](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44142/36217) provide alternative solutions for this issue. If I had any of these libs in the current project, I'd probably use them instead.

Comment: You are mainly asking for a based-opinion answer, in my case the first approach has proven to be more clear when I need to choose between both, but it is just my case.

Comment: I assume that last `reader.readLine();` should be `line = reader.readLine();`?

Comment: tobias_k: yes, thanks. I've fixed it. 
morgano: well, it is a question about coding guidelines, and most such questions are opinion-based. Still, I would like to know if majority prefers one of these options or if there is no strong preference. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: I consider `demoA` to be idiomatic for Java. That said, there's an old SO question on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677411/iterating-over-the-content-of-a-text-file-line-by-line-is-there-a-best-practic Especially the highest-rated (not accepted) answer is interesting.

Comment: I don't write `String line = null;` but `String line;`.

Comment: I think one of the main things to consider here is that you're dealing with a `BufferedReader` and that has been using that idiom since the beginning of Java. If you did it with something OTHER than a buffered reader, people might not know what you're doing, but because you're reading a line at a time, that's something most Java developers have seen and will recognize immediately.

Comment: What about `while (null != (line = ...))`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Assignment inside a condition is ok in this case, as the assignment is surrounded by an extra pair of parentheses – the comparison is obviously `!= null`, there is no chance that we wanted to type `line == reader.readLine()`.

However, a `for` loop might actually be more elegant here:

```
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    doSomething(line);
}
```

Alternatively, we could do this which also restricts the scope of `line` as with the `for`-loop, and additionally eliminates unnecessary repetition:

```
while (true) {
    final String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;

    doSomething(line);
}
```

I like this solution most because it doesn't mutate any variables.

Comment: +1 for `for` loop. I hadn't thought about it before but that is clear and avoids having `line` outside of the loop scope.

Comment: I also like the for loop solution. It is dense, readable and does not draw attention away from `doSomething(line)`.

Comment: In the second loop: why always create a new final String and not put the a variable before the while?

Comment: There's a special construct in C++ to keep the outer scope free of garbage variables: `while (int a = f()) { ... }`. I think that it's fine to write such code.

Comment: @FabioF. I do not create a `new String` each time, that happens anyway because of `readLine`. It is however considered a best practice to restrict the visibility of variables to the smallest possible scope. Here, this means the `line` should not be declared outside of the loop. Not reassigning variables and other aspects of immutability are a good habit I picked up when doing functional programming: This makes code easier to understand as the variable name and its value can be used interchangeably (“referential transparency”), there is no mutating state I have to keep in mind.

Comment: @amon what about
    `{String line; while(...){...}}`

Comment: @FabioF. While that would restrict the visibility properly, it adds an unnecessary level of indentation. And we might just as well use an equivalent `for (String line; ...;) { ... }` instead – all of the advantages, none of the downsides.

Comment: Got my upvote... good answer, except for having the 1-liner suggestion: `if (line == null) break;` which is contrary to [Java code-style guidelines (7.4)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449)

Comment: I like the last solution best.  It's often a good idea to avoid having loop exit points which are separated by code that has meaningful side-effects, but if the natural location for the loop exit point is in the middle, it's better to use a while/break construct than duplicate the code which should precede the loop exit point.

Comment: The while (true) suggestion works especially well if the code to get the next item to be processed is less trivial than here. In trivial cases it doesn't really matter what pattern you use because it's trivial anyway, but this pattern works fine with complex cases as well. It avoids duplicating this code at the end of the loop, which is error prone if the code in the loop gets longer and might contain a continue statement. Which is quite common, if you structure your code like "get line; exit if no more lines; check if line should be ignored; process line; "

Comment: @EmilyL., I disagree about the `for` loop. While the code is _functional_, a `for` loop is semantically for a specific number of iterations (including iterating over a collection/array) while a `while` loop is semantically for an unknown number of iterations (such as reading from a file). Both loop variants _can_ be constructed using the other, of course, but that's not the point.

Comment: @BrianS While true in the naive case, Java's introduction of the `for-each` construct in 1.5 has lead to a bit of coloring to the meaning of a `for` loop. To use in such a loop, an object must implement `Iterable`, but nothing about that interface implies that the number of objects produced by the iterator returned by `Iterable.iterator()` must be specific. A reasonable example would be the `Iterable` solution from Arian's answer; you do not know how many lines the `Iterable` will produce, but each line is its own element to operate on and thus the `each` still has meaning.

Answer (score 22):

You could increase the abstraction level of the code a little bit with an iterator-like pattern and the same time you could reuse an existing library (with the experience of the authors) for that: [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) [LineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html). It would replace the null check to a little bit readable `hasNext()`/`nextLine()`.

Using an iterator hides an unnecessary detail: the reader returns `null` when there is no more data. The `hasNext()` method is closer to the (English) language, the code is easier to read. You still can check the details inside `LineIterator` if you need that but usually readers/maintainers happier with a higher level overview of the method which is easier to understand. ([This answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42504/7076) and question contain an expressive example.)

A sample method:

```
private void demoC(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    final LineIterator it = new LineIterator(reader);
    try {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String line = it.nextLine();
            // do something with line
        }
    } finally {
        it.close();
    }
}
```

See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)

Comment: We don't use Apache Commons IO on this project, but thanks for a pointer!

Comment: @mkalkov: It's just simple a class with a couple of lines, so you can create your own version or copy the implementation into your project (but check the license before that).

Comment: Of course you can increase the abstraction level. But why would you? What are the benefits?

Comment: @gnasher729: Good question, thanks! I've updated the answer, check it please.

Comment: For the sake of testing line = null, you now have to learn about a non-standard LineIterator class which is found deep in some library, you have to know that the iterator has a "hasNext" method, you have to know that you get the next line by calling "nextLine", you have to know to call "close" on the iterator, you added exception handling, there are 8 lines of boilerplate code instead of 3, the actual code is now three levels deeply nested before it even starts instead of two, excuse me if I'm not impressed at all.

Comment: @gnasher729: Two things to consider: 1. `close` just closes the reader which is missing from the original code. 2. code is read more than written, so it's worth to optimize for reading.

Comment: Why are you using this iterator manually instead of inside a foreach loop?

Comment: @Phoshi: unfortunately foreach can't use `Iterator`, it needs and `Iterable`.

Comment: @palacsint: Ah, of course. I guess my question is then why on earth LineIterator doesn't implement Iterable, but I suppose that isn't something you can answer.

Comment: @Phoshi: You can pass any reader (with any stream) to the `LineIterator`. Some of them might not support `reset` (and can be read only once, like a network socket). Rereading multiple times requires creating multiple iterators with `Iterable.iterator()`.

Comment: @palacsint: Isn't that exactly the same scenario as here, though? A foreach loop effectively compiles down into the code you have here, you still can't iterate over either more than once safely.

Comment: @palacsint None of `Iterator`, `Iterable`, and `LineIterator` support `reset` either, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @JAB: reset is for streams. You could create a `LineIterable` whose `iterator()` method could call `reset` on the underlying stream. (It would have disadvantages, like it's not too easy to support concurrent iterators.)

Comment: @Phoshi: Yes, it is but foreach does not support that.

Comment: @palacsint: foreach just calls .next until .hasNext is false, the only issue would come around if you tried to enumerate /twice/... which is exactly the same in this case. I'm still not seeing why it couldn't be an iterable.

Comment: @palacsint Sure you could, and you could also subclass `LineIterator` into `ResettingLineIterator` and have the constructor reset the reader. The argument against `Iterable` at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-181 is for implementing both interfaces on the same object and is perfectly reasonable, but any arguments against a `LineIterable` class separate from `LineIterator` that returns a new iterator for each `iterator()` call apply equally to `LineIterator` itself due to the nature of the underlying `Reader`.

Comment: (Not to mention that using multiple `LineIterator`s for concurrency would possibly be worse than a `LineIterable` class as each of those `LineIterator`s could close the `Reader`, which would invalidate any other `LineIterator`s on that `Reader` even if it were one supporting `mark`/`reset`/`skip` and the iterators were subclassed to keep track of their positions independently [though you could also override `LineIterator.close()` to not actually call `Reader.close()` until all iterators for that `Reader` have closed/been consumed - perhaps a concurrent `Map<Reader, Integer>` for the counts?]).

Comment: Of course, in Java 8 you'd do something like `BufferedReader rf; if (reader instanceof BufferedReader) rf = (BufferedReader) reader; else rf = new BufferedReader(reader); rf.lines().forEach(line -> do_something(line));` and all this arguing goes away (to be replaced by arguing over whether a functional programming style is truly appropriate for Java and whether it improves readability or not and so on... though the ability of streams to be internally concurrent is pretty nice).

Comment: @Phoshi: Oh, I see your point now. It could be `Iterable` but people at Apache didn't choose that. I think it would be easy to misunderstood and could cause some headache when one wants to use it in two foreach loops. So, it could be but I'm not sure that I would like that or not.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of wrapping the reader in an iterator, you could also wrap it in an `Iterable` that then returns the iterator.

It would allow you to write the following

```
for (String line: linesOf(reader)) {
     // ...
}
```

which makes very clean code.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, `demoA()` is fine just as it is.

Assignment as a side effect within a test is normally frowned upon, but this usage is an excellent example of why the language feature exists.  It's compact, non-repetitive, idiomatic, and efficient.  Use it, and don't feel guilty about it!

Answer (score 3):

Please realize that

```
if (cond(var = expr))
```

can usually be rewritten as

```
var = expr;
if (cond(var)) ...
```

and

```
while (cond(var = expr))
```

can *always* be rewritten as

```
for (var = expr; cond(var); var = expr)
```

without even affecting the meaning of `break;` or `continue;` in the loop.

So there is quite rarely a definite need for cramming assignments into conditionals' conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do something like this as well:

```
Files.lines(path)
```

It gets all the lines from the file as a stream, then you can sort the string based on your logic and then collect the same in a list and write to the output file.

This answer gives you a functional programming approach. Most part of the method is self-explanatory.

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(path)).map(--Your business logic--);
```

There are various functions available in the steam API which can make your processing easy.