# How many squares can you see?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

With a positive outlook, I posted [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24904/how-many-squares-can-you-see) at [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).  I tried to come up with my own solution to the challenge which is as follows:

---

The output is *displayed* (not yet exported to GIF) on a class extending `JPanel`:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Display extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private int points;
    private int xRed;
    private int yRed;
    private int side;
    // Side of the smallest square:
    private static final int sideC = 80;
    private static final int offSet = 20;
    private Thread t;
    private boolean stop;
    private static final long updatePeriod = 1000;

    public Display(int points) {
        this.side = sideC;
        this.points = points;
        yRed = offSet;
        xRed = yRed - side;
        stop = false;
        repaint();
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        // The stroke to apply.
        BasicStroke stroke;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(5.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
        g2D.setStroke(stroke);
        // Let the painting begin!
        g2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2D.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getWidth());

        g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // paint the main grid.
        for (int i = 0; i < points * sideC; i += sideC) {
            for (int j = 0; j < points * sideC; j += sideC) {
                g2D.drawRect(offSet + i, offSet + j, sideC, sideC);
            }
        }
        // Paint the red square.
        if (sideC * points >= side) {
            g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2D.drawRect(xRed, yRed, side, side);
        } else {
            side = sideC;
            yRed = offSet;
            xRed = offSet - sideC;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (side <= points * sideC && !stop) {
            while (yRed < offSet + points * sideC && !stop) {
                long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
                repaint();
                xRed += sideC;
                if (xRed >= offSet + (points + 1) * sideC - side) {
                    xRed = offSet;
                    yRed += sideC;
                }
                if (yRed >= offSet + (points + 1) * sideC - side) {
                    yRed = offSet;
                    xRed = offSet - sideC;
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(xRed + "\t" + yRed + "\t" + side);
                try {
                    s = System.currentTimeMillis()- s;
                    s = s > 0 ? s : 500;
                    t.sleep(updatePeriod - s);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
            side += sideC;
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        stop = false;
        t = new Thread(this, "Hello!");
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stopping");
        stop = true;
        t = null;
    }
}
```

The class extending `JFrame` is a very simple one (till now):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Squares extends JFrame {

    public Squares() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(Squares.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new Display(5));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { // Java 8 - lambda expression
            new Squares();
        });
    }
}
```

---

Sample output is:

[image: img1][image: img2]

---

Any help regarding simplification of the code, refactoring, cleaning up, improvisation, improving efficiency, the overall technique through comments, answers, downvotes (and perhaps upvotes?) would be greatly appreciated. Remarks on improving its *elegance* would be great!

Answer (score 8):

1. A great comment from [*@tb-*'s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/19459/7076):

   > Do not extend `JPanel`, instead have a private `JPanel` 
   >   attribute and deal with it (Encapsulation). 
   >   There is no need to give access to all 
   >   `JPanel` methods for code dealing with a `UserPanel`
   >   instance. If you extend, you are forced to stay with this forever, 
   >   if you encapsulate, you can change whenever you want without 
   >   taking care of something outside the class.

   The is true for `JFrame`. It would also make `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` unnecessary.

   So `Squares` would be something like this:

   ```
   public class Squares {

       private final JFrame squareFrame = new JFrame();

       public Squares() {
           squareFrame.setSize(500, 500);
           squareFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           squareFrame.setContentPane(new Display(5));
           squareFrame.setVisible(true);
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread):

   > all user interface components should be created and **accessed** only from the AWT event dispatch thread.

   including `repaint()` in the `run` method (which is run by another thread). You should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait` for this too:

   ```
   try {
       SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> repaint());
   } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       Thread.interrupted();
       break;
   }
   ```
3. Be careful about thread-safety. If you call `repaint()` on EDT it will use `xRed`, `yRed` etc from multiple threads (EDT and your own thread), so you need proper synchronization for visibility:

   > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

   Source: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*

   > Locking is not just about mutual exclusion; it is also about memory visibility.
   >   To ensure that all threads see the most up-to-date values of shared mutable 
   >   variables, the reading and writing threads must synchronize on a common lock.

   Source: *Java Concurrency in Practice, 3.1.3. Locking and Visibility*.

   `stop` also suffers from proper synchronization. Changing its value (from another thread) might not be visible to your thread. For this I'd suggest you using an `AtomicBoolean` (which is thread safe).

   For doing proper synchronization between the timer thread and EDT you need to restructure the code but I guess it would be much easier with [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) than your custom thread. It looks like that it has been designed for exactly these kind of problems.
4. I would create another class for the `Runnable`/`run` implementation to fulfill the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Currently it has too many responsibilities: draws the current state, update the current state, starts/stops the updating thread. It could be splitted to at least three classes. (You might not need this if you use Swing Timers - I'm not too familiar with them.)
5. Calling overridable methods (like `stop`) from constructors is not a good practice. Child classes could see partially initialized objects in the overridden method. The `stop` should be `final` here. See [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/843804) and *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance, or else prohibit it*
6. The code calls a static method here on an instance which is misleading:

   > ```
   > t.sleep(updatePeriod - s);
   > ```

   It should be the following:

   ```
   Thread.sleep(updatePeriod - s);
   ```
7. The code never calls `stop`. If it's not necessary remove it, otherwise use it.
8. I'd use longer variable names than these ones:

   > ```
   > private Thread t;
   > long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
   > ```

   Choose variable names which describes their purpose. `t` could be `updateThread` and `s` could be `currentTimeMillis` ro `frameStartTime`.
9. According to the Java Code Conventions, constants should be `UPPERCASED_WITH_UNDERSCORES`:

   > ```
   > private static final int sideC = 80;
   > private static final int offSet = 20;
   > private static final long updatePeriod = 1000;
   > ```
10. > ```
    > BasicStroke stroke;
    > stroke = new BasicStroke(5.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    > ```

    This could be one line:

    > ```
    > BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    > ```
11. Use method names instead of commenting:

    > ```
    > // paint the main grid.
    > for (int i = 0; i < points * sideC; i += sideC) {
    >     for (int j = 0; j < points * sideC; j += sideC) {
    >         g2D.drawRect(offSet + i, offSet + j, sideC, sideC);
    >     }
    > }
    > // Paint the red square.
    > if (sideC * points >= side) {
    >     g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
    >     g2D.drawRect(xRed, yRed, side, side);
    > } else {
    >     side = sideC;
    >     yRed = offSet;
    >     xRed = offSet - sideC;
    > }
    > ```

    It could be:

    ```
    paintMainGrid(g2D);
    paintRedSquare(g2D);

    ...

    private void paintMainGrid(Graphics2D g2D) {
        for (int i = 0; i < points * sideC; i += sideC) {
            for (int j = 0; j < points * sideC; j += sideC) {
                g2D.drawRect(offSet + i, offSet + j, sideC, sideC);
            }
        }
    }

    private void paintRedSquare(Graphics2D g2D) {
        if (sideC * points >= side) {
            g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2D.drawRect(xRed, yRed, side, side);
        } else {
            side = sideC;
            yRed = offSet;
            xRed = offSet - sideC;
        }
    }
    ```

    Using these methods hides unnecessary details, increases the abstraction level of the code and it's easier to read. You still can check the details inside `paintMainGrid` and `paintRedSquare` if you need that but usually readers/maintainers happier with a higher level overview of the method which is easier to understand. ([This answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42504/7076) and question contain another example.)

    (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable*, p67)

Comment: This is why I love this more than [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)! :-)

Comment: Also, could you _please_ [elaborate] a bit more on points 1. 2. and 3. (preferrably all!) with some _very simple example code_?

Comment: @ambigram_maker: I'm glad to hear that :) If you have time feel free to help us graduating, I bet you can find another useful questions answers on the site (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swing) to [vote on](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/612/7076).

Comment: @ambigram_maker: Answer updated, check it.

Comment: Could you help me on one more tiny aspect? I believe that the `while` loop i'm using can be improved. Could I get some suggestions?

Comment: @ambigram_maker: I don't have time now but I'll try to check it later.

Answer (score 1):

A few minor notes about the nested loops:

1. First, I'd create guard clauses for the stop flag instead of the `&&`. I've found that easier to follow:

   ```
   while (side <= points * sideC) {
       if (stop) {
           return;
       }
       while (yRed < offSet + points * sideC) {
           if (stop) {
               return;
           }
           ...
       }
       ...

   }
   ```

   (If you use Swing Timers, I guess you won't need it at all.)
2. Then, `points` is `final`, `offset` and `sideC` are `static final`, so you could use a few explanatory variable before the loops:

   ```
   final int maxSide = points * sideC;
   while (side <= maxSide) {
       if (stop) {
           return;
       }
       final int maxYRed = offSet + maxSide;
       while (yRed < maxYRed) {
           if (stop) {
               return;
           }
   ```

   Feel free to choose better names, I'm just guessing here.

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*;  *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*)
3. `offSet + (points + 1) * sideC` also never changes it could also have an explanatory variable.

That's all I have now, maybe somebody could do a more in depth review. If not, feel free to post [a follow-up question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/7076) with the refactored code.